# What is a good method for computing the $N$-dimensional volume of a subset of a spherization of a cone?

Tags: algorithms

I have a pointed polyhedral cone $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$, with the vertex at the origin.  Cone $C$ is known to be the intersection of $2 (^{N+1}_{\; \;2})$ closed half-spaces.

Furthermore, there is a set $S$ (bounded away from the origin.  I need to estimate what "fraction" of the generating rays of $C$ meets $S$, in the sense of a suitable $N$-dimensional volume defined on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$.

I suspect, one way to do this is by clever sampling on the sphere (actually, can't think of any others at the moment).  The challenge is that the sampling should be confined to the intersection of the sphere and $C$.  Are there known methods?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This paper may help (I cannot easily access the full paper, so I am not certain,
but certainly the title and abstract indicate it is relevant.)

> Stefanescu, Stefan V. "Generating uniform random points inside a cone." *Monte Carlo Methods and Applications* 6.2 (2000): 115-130. ([Journal link](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/mcma.2000.6.issue-2/mcma.2000.6.2.115/mcma.2000.6.2.115.xml).)

---

[image: ConeAbs]

---

The paper reviews previous work, so its bibliography may be useful as well.